# Having trouble with regex for Treesize

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all documents  that contain the following symbols in their name using Treesize Pro's file search:

```
#
% 
:
•
```

For whatever reason, the normal wildcard search function won't process `*#*` which is my primary offender, so I'm stuck doing regular expressions.

And yes, the 4th one there is a bullet point. If that one can't be done, I won't lose too much sleep - only 30-40 of those on the system somewhere.

Comment: Regular expressions are just for that: searching for patterns. It pays to learn using it: especially in your case, you do 1 search instead of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeSize online manual has some tips regarding regular expressions, maybe this could be a starting point?

This is a [direct link](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/online_manual/EN/regular_expressions.html) to the chapter, alternatively you can use the [search](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/manual.php).

Comment: Sigh - it never occured to me that they would have their own documentation on regex. The one example rule on there got me going in the right direction:    `[^(A-Za-z)]`

Comment: Updated link to manual: https://manuals.jam-software.com/treesize/EN/